# Laravel 10 Auth0 and 404labfr/laravel-impersonate

Tags: laravel, auth0, impersonation

I'm using 404labfr/laravel-impersonate and auth0 7.12. When I impersonate using $manager->take(), there are some keys that are set in session, but after I do a redirect to a route with the auth middleware and if I do a dd(session()->all()) inside the middleware those keys doesn't exist anymore.

Is there a possibility that auth0 could be doing this?

```
$manager->take($from, $to, 'web');
return redirect()->route('home');
```

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
   
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        dd(session()->all());

        return parent::handle($request, $next, ...$guards);
    }
}
```

Thanks